# Sketch pad integrated into the Question area (as a Markdown option)

Tags: feature-request

There are a lot of times when a simple sketch would help get the point accross on many of the StackExchange questions/answers. What would people think of integrating a Sketch markdown option alongside the code sample and image tags?

There are good open-source javascript options out there, and they could possibly be integrated into the StackExchange site.

E.g. the following gui example would be very difficult to explain, and people generally dont bother sketching ideas outside of StackExchange and uploading them - i think it would be a brilliant option

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I find this an interesting idea, but I am not sure I can get behind it.

Unless this will save bandwidth for StackExchange versus image uploading (would it?), I would rather that people make more professional sketches in the tools available to them.

If the issue is that people (feel they) have no tools available, then I suppose providing links to online sketch tools would be useful.

I am not against this idea, but I would like to hear a more complete case for it.

Comment: It would save bandwidth id say.... look at http://ianli.com/sketchpad/ for instance, the sketch is just saved as text in JSON format. But more importantly, it is very very rare that images or diagrams are included with questions or answers - do you agree? If overuse was a concern, then only allow for users of a certain rep

Comment: @Brian As a *Mathematica* user, images and diagrams are easy to make, and viewing the [tag:mathematica] tag you will see that there are quite a few pictures included in posts.  If other areas are lacking needed illustrations then it would be helpful, at the least, to encourage users to include them.  If providing a sketch pad can be proven to increase a beneficial use of illustrations (rather than merely being used for amusement), then I will support it.  If it saves money for SysOps compared to imgur, then all the more.